# Python: how to plot a series of regions in a stacked/layered way?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have several different regions that measure the 2-d spatial event of something given a condition.  The condition is encoded with the color of the region.  The regions in general are polygons (even though I've plotted circles) and can have holes in them, as in:

[image]

To increase clarity of visualization, I have been requested to turn this into what has been called a "wedding cake plot", where each region has a vertical offset from each other, with vertical sides around each region.  Something kind of like the following Paint image:

[image]

How to go about doing this with Matplotlib, or some other Python plotting package?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something with `plot_surface` like this:

```
# sample data
data = np.zeros((20,24))
data[2:18, 2:18] = 1
data[4:16, 4:16] = 2
data[6:14,6:14] = 3
data[8:12,8:12] = 2

# 2D view
plt.imshow(data, cmap='Reds')

# mesh
X,Y=np.mgrid[0:data.shape[0], 0:data.shape[1]]


# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, data, cmap='hot',
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Output:

[image]

**Note** You would need to hierarchically label your data correctly.

Comment: This wasn't quite what I was looking for (close though!), but it helped me get on the right path.  Now I use matplotlib.PolyCollection() and axes.add_collection3d to get the polygons.  I haven't been able to get any thickness to the polygons though.

My data are not in a grid format, which is why I wasn't able to use your method directly.

Answer (score 0):

The plotly library has a function to draw a funnel, so you can use that instead. The following is a graph from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/funnel-charts/#setting-marker-size-and-color), with some modifications to make it look the way you want.

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

x_sorted = sorted([39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2])
y_sorted = ["Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"]
fig = go.Figure(go.Funnel(
    y = y_sorted[::-1],
    x = x_sorted,
    marker={'color':['black','yellow','green','blue','red']})
               )
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I need something 3-d, more like what @quanghong's answer has.  Sorry if that wasn't made clear.

Comment: I didn't understand that 3D is a must. I'm not sure what you want to express as visualization.